# Converting List into Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a package which returns `list` in variable "res".
res[1] looks like this

```
> res[1]
$anoms
            timestamp anoms
1 2017-02-08 20:15:00  7695
2 2017-06-09 20:26:00  4013
3 2017-02-01 20:14:00 85029
4 2017-02-07 20:14:00  7214
5 2017-09-23 08:49:00  4422
6 2017-01-31 20:14:00 84431
7 2017-09-22 08:47:00  4529
```

As you can see both columns (timestamp and anoms) are in 1 position.

How can I transform this list into a Data Frame with three columns, where 1st and 2nd are timestamp and anoms, and third is a static variable which was defined before (say variable `a<-"test")`

Comment: `df = res[1]$anoms ; df$a = "test"` ?

Comment: @useR, thanks. Sorry if question was too easy, I'm just learning. You can post answer if you would like

Comment: Glad that this is helpful. There's never a question that's too easy. Everyone's learning :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this as an answer so people can see it:

```
df = res[1]$anoms 
df$a = "test"
```

You can use `$` to extract the `anoms` element of the list (which is a data.frame in this case).

Comment: @UserR, one quick question, why this is not working? df = df$a = "test" ; res[2]$anoms

Comment: @Sher Your syntax is incorrect. It should be `df = res[2]$anoms ; df$a = "test"` assuming that `anoms` is an element of `res[2]`